# input target value with jquery

Tags: jquery, input, target

Hi I've tried a few different ways of doing this but nothings working for me, I'm using a system that I cannot physically edit the code I need. I have an input with the following code

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl10$loginImageButton" value="Logout" id="ctl10_loginImageButton"     class="cssloginImageButtonlogout cssbutton">
```

And all I need to do is change the value of the value from "Logout" to "GO" using jQuery

If someone could help i'd appreciate it I'm starting to pull my hair out now :/
Thanks

Comment: it sure would be nice if you showed one or two of the things you tried, so it didn't seem like you were just getting us to write your code for you.

Comment: Have you Goog: *"how to change/add/set input value with jQuery"* ?

Comment: It would also help us see your misunderstanding, so we can educate you better. You won't learn anything from just getting the code.

Comment: You have the following syntax error on your page: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } home.aspx:357` This is stopping script execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=submit]").val("Go");
});
```

OR can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ctl10_loginImageButton").val("Go");
});
```

Make sure that you are including the JS at right place. means it should be only for this page. If you want to change the Text only this button.

Comment: If the JS is included just before the closing body tag, there is no need for the $(document).ready(function(){...});

Comment: @JackZelig and if not written there then ..... how you can imagine that it will be but my code will execute in each condition.

Comment: No probs :) I just hate seeing these $(document).ready statements all over the web when they are very seldom necessary.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help guys, these still are not changing it for me though. could it possibly be the system blocking the change? it was built in ASP. I thought jQuery would have bypassed this though

Comment: @user2791952 I don't think it affects in any way ,JQuery is a Client-Side language for manipulation and lot of other stuff ,There may be a possibility if you haven't included any JQuery reference .

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick for you:

```
$("input[value='Logout']").val("GO");
```

jQuery makes it easy to select any element by attribute and alter it accordingly.
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#ctl10_loginImageButton').val('GO');
```

OR

```
$('input[value=Logout]').val('GO');
```